# Invalid Hash Function Name on SHA2-512 when creating user

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Trying to create user using from golang using library "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1"

As docs sad here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User hashFunction could be MD5, DES, SHA2-256, SHA2-512, so i'm writing code:

```
hash := sha512.Sum512([]byte("random password value))
encoded := hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])

payload := &admin.User{
    Password:     "$6$" + encoded,
    HashFunction: "SHA2-512"
}
```

This results: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Hash Function Name, invalid

So how to understand, whats wrong with hash function name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found here https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html#insert that right now only supported SHA-1, crypt and MD5, so documentation is wrong, and for SHA2 hashes use string "crypt" as hashFunction value and add to password corresponding crypt prefix ( for example for SHA2-512 add $6$ to hex encoded value )

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to also include a salt, for the backend to accept the password (not sure if this is dependent on the domain).  Otherwise I got the error "googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Password, invalid" when trying to call users.insert.

For example, if using SHA-256, the crypt format is:

```
$5$salt$hash
```

Pseudo-code example:

```
salt := "some random string"
password := "I'm a password <= 100 chars"
hash = sha256sum(passsword + salt)

crypt := "$5$" + hexEncode(salt) + "$" + hexEncode(password)
```

The magic number`$5$` depends on the hash function used.

- Use `$1$` for DES, or MD5
- Use `$5$` for SHA-256
- Use `$6$` for SHA-512

Then the hashFunction is set to `crypt`.

From: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User

More about the c `crypt` lib (not to be confused with the Unix utility of the same name), with valid hash examples that can be tested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29